# Binary XML file line #75: Error inflating class

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, layout-inflater

I'm following the tutorial in http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/ to create a facebook like newsfeed. But I'm getting the following error and I cannot understand it.
Any help is appreciated.

My logcat is as follows.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #75: Error inflating class info.androidhive.listviewfeed.FeedImageView
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                                                                     at example.com.samplemad.adapter.FeedListAdapter.getView(FeedListAdapter.java:61)
                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: info.androidhive.listviewfeed.FeedImageView
                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
                                                                     at example.com.samplemad.adapter.FeedListAdapter.getView(FeedListAdapter.java:61) 
                                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267) 
                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244) 
                                                                     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156) 
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814) 
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390) 
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681) 
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574) 
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814) 
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814) 
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390) 
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681) 
                                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574) 
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814) 
                                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148) 
                                                                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848) 
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100) 
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273) 
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998) 
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212) 
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725) 
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555) 
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525) 
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Following is my Adapter class.

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return feedItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
    TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
    TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
    NetworkImageView profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
    FeedImageView feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

    FeedItem item = feedItems.get(position);

    name.setText(item.getName());

    // Converting timestamp into x ago format
    CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
            System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

    // Chcek for empty status message
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
        statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // status is empty, remove from view
        statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // Checking for null feed url
    if (item.getUrl() != null) {
        url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

        // Making url clickable
        url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // url is null, remove from the view
        url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // user profile pic
    profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

    // Feed image
    if (item.getImge() != null) {
        feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        feedImageView
                .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                    }
                });
    } else {
        feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
  }

}
```

And this is my FeedImageView.java class

```
public class FeedImageView extends ImageView {

public interface ResponseObserver {
    public void onError();

    public void onSuccess();
}

private ResponseObserver mObserver;

public void setResponseObserver(ResponseObserver observer) {
    mObserver = observer;
}

/**
 * The URL of the network image to load
 */
private String mUrl;

/**
 * Resource ID of the image to be used as a placeholder until the network
 * image is loaded.
 */
private int mDefaultImageId;

/**
 * Resource ID of the image to be used if the network response fails.
 */
private int mErrorImageId;

/**
 * Local copy of the ImageLoader.
 */
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

/**
 * Current ImageContainer. (either in-flight or finished)
 */
private ImageLoader.ImageContainer mImageContainer;

public FeedImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public FeedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public FeedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                     int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * Sets URL of the image that should be loaded into this view. Note that
 * calling this will immediately either set the cached image (if available)
 * or the default image specified by
 * {@link //VolleyImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} on the view.
 *
 * NOTE: If applicable, {@link //VolleyImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)}
 * and {@link //VolleyImageView#setErrorImageResId(int)} should be called
 * prior to calling this function.
 *
 * @param url
 *            The URL that should be loaded into this ImageView.
 * @param imageLoader
 *            ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
 */
public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
    mUrl = url;
    mImageLoader = imageLoader;
    // The URL has potentially changed. See if we need to load it.
    loadImageIfNecessary(false);
}

/**
 * Sets the default image resource ID to be used for this view until the
 * attempt to load it completes.
 */
public void setDefaultImageResId(int defaultImage) {
    mDefaultImageId = defaultImage;
}

/**
 * Sets the error image resource ID to be used for this view in the event
 * that the image requested fails to load.
 */
public void setErrorImageResId(int errorImage) {
    mErrorImageId = errorImage;
}

/**
 * Loads the image for the view if it isn't already loaded.
 *
 * @param isInLayoutPass
 *            True if this was invoked from a layout pass, false otherwise.
 */
private void loadImageIfNecessary(final boolean isInLayoutPass) {
    final int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    boolean isFullyWrapContent = getLayoutParams() != null
            && getLayoutParams().height == LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            && getLayoutParams().width == LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    // if the view's bounds aren't known yet, and this is not a
    // wrap-content/wrap-content
    // view, hold off on loading the image.
    if (width == 0 && height == 0 && !isFullyWrapContent) {
        return;
    }

    // if the URL to be loaded in this view is empty, cancel any old
    // requests and clear the
    // currently loaded image.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUrl)) {
        if (mImageContainer != null) {
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            mImageContainer = null;
        }
        setDefaultImageOrNull();
        return;
    }

    // if there was an old request in this view, check if it needs to be
    // canceled.
    if (mImageContainer != null && mImageContainer.getRequestUrl() != null) {
        if (mImageContainer.getRequestUrl().equals(mUrl)) {
            // if the request is from the same URL, return.
            return;
        } else {
            // if there is a pre-existing request, cancel it if it's
            // fetching a different URL.
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            setDefaultImageOrNull();
        }
    }

    // The pre-existing content of this view didn't match the current URL.
    // Load the new image
    // from the network.
    ImageLoader.ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
            new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (mErrorImageId != 0) {
                        setImageResource(mErrorImageId);
                    }

                    if (mObserver != null) {
                        mObserver.onError();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(final ImageLoader.ImageContainer response,
                                       boolean isImmediate) {
                    // If this was an immediate response that was delivered
                    // inside of a layout
                    // pass do not set the image immediately as it will
                    // trigger a requestLayout
                    // inside of a layout. Instead, defer setting the image
                    // by posting back to
                    // the main thread.
                    if (isImmediate && isInLayoutPass) {
                        post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                onResponse(response, false);
                            }
                        });
                        return;
                    }

                    int bWidth = 0, bHeight = 0;
                    if (response.getBitmap() != null) {

                        setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                        bWidth = response.getBitmap().getWidth();
                        bHeight = response.getBitmap().getHeight();
                        adjustImageAspect(bWidth, bHeight);

                    } else if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
                        setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
                    }

                    if (mObserver != null) {
                        mObserver.onSuccess();

                    }
                }
            });

    // update the ImageContainer to be the new bitmap container.
    mImageContainer = newContainer;

}

private void setDefaultImageOrNull() {
    if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
        setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
    } else {
        setImageBitmap(null);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
                        int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    loadImageIfNecessary(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    if (mImageContainer != null) {
        // If the view was bound to an image request, cancel it and clear
        // out the image from the view.
        mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
        setImageBitmap(null);
        // also clear out the container so we can reload the image if
        // necessary.
        mImageContainer = null;
    }
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
}

@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    invalidate();
}

/*
 * Adjusting imageview height
 * */
private void adjustImageAspect(int bWidth, int bHeight) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();

    if (bWidth == 0 || bHeight == 0)
        return;

    int swidth = getWidth();
    int new_height = 0;
    new_height = swidth * bHeight / bWidth;
    params.width = swidth;
    params.height = new_height;
    setLayoutParams(params);
  }

}
```

Comment: there is some problem in the xml that you are using . Post the xml code and point the line number 75 in it.

Comment: The Error clearly states that there is an Error in Line 75 in your XML, Try changing the package name of the class you are using in XML line 75 and then tell me if that helped you or not

Comment: Yes, I found the error. It was a misspelling in the package name. Thank you very much both of you. Cheers!

Comment: @Lak : an Upvote or accepting the answer is appreciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Packege name in you XML line 75 from **info.androidhive.listviewfeed.FeedImageView** to**your packagename.FeedImageView**
Try this and tell me if I can help you any more with this error